# Node.js + Socket.io memory leak and max listener

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm node.js beginner. Trying to create simple chat app, but have problem. When refreshed page fast 10+ times I have warning:

> (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

When I disabled socket.io, this warning disapears. So, problem with socket.io. How to increase max listeners for socket.io? Or maybe another solution?

Code:

```
var http = require('http')
fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, response) {
    req.setMaxListeners(0);
    var pathname = __dirname + '/index.html'

    fs.readFile(pathname, "binary", function(err, file) {
        if (err) {
            response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            response.end(err);
        } else {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write(file, "binary");
            response.end();
       }
    });
});

io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(4567);
```

Comment: Why do you set `maxListener` in the first place? Maybe GC is to slow. Also I am not sure if socket.io is fine in this quite incomplete state you are using it.

Comment: I put just little example here. I'm going to use websockets on client and server. But now I have to fix memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem, but try this:

```
io.setMaxListeners(0);
```

Comment: Already tried that. Also tried io.sockets.setMaxListeners(0). Doesn't solve problem.

Comment: Well, it *is* just a warning so you could just ignore it :)

Comment: Yes, but at the same time I see a huge increase in memory usage. Up to 60-80%, but without socket.io - just 1-2%.

Comment: Is the code in your question exactly the code you're testing with?

Comment: Sure. And problem just occur when I fast refresh page several times. I think it should not be.

Comment: I agree. Sadly, I can't reproduce it (latest versions of everything). I guessed the client-side part of it, though (just an `io.connect`).

Comment: This completely hangs up my node js server like an exception when running on local when i press control + C other processing start. I have tried setting maxListeners no use, 
What is it saying is it i have too many guys connected to same listeners or is it saying i have too many events

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the top of your code to increase the emitter limit globally

`require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;`